# Is there a client side function to save record in Suitescript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to use the saveRecord entry point of a client side script to redirect to another page.

However, in order to do that, my understanding is that I need to save and submit the record first.

Is there a way to do this (basically replicate what happens when a user presses Netsuite's native 'save' button on a record) using a client side script (i.e. without the user clicking that button)?

I have tried record.submitfields though this does not trigger the function under saveRecord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a pure SuiteScript solution, it is more like a pure JavaScript/Html solution I'm using without a problem in my code; if you keep in mind that Netsuite UI is just a Web Application (It is just a Web Site!), then on the Client Scripts you can do a lot of things not available as standard SuiteScript.

In your case, you simply need to trigger the click event of the standard "Save" button within your code, and because Netsuite uses jQuery, then you can do it like this:

```
// your code
jQuery('#btn_multibutton_submitter').click();
// #btn_multibutton_submitter is just an example, get the right id of your button by checking the Netsuite page source code, or using Chrome Inspect
```

Comment: Once again, thank you B. Assem for both your help with the code and the easy to understand explanation. 

I am only just beginning to learn how to code so really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to redirect into a record url, you can use the 'N/url' module and call url.resolveRecord() API right after saving:

```
 url.resolveRecord({
     recordType: record.Type.EMPLOYEE,    
     isEditMode: true,
     params:{}
 })
```

This would be an example for Employee record types.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo. I had tried this though was having issues with the trigger for the client script. i.e. I was trying to redirect after save though the 'save' event wasn't occurring since that was dependent on the user clicking the 'save' button (which B. Assem provided a solution to in his answer below)

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is that you trigger a save -- and [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70925278/1189625) is fine for that.

However, for the key requirement of

> [after save] to redirect to another page.

this is tricker because the save it going to reload the page and thus it will refresh a bunch of things.

a) Are you okay opening a new tab? if so then open a new tab with `window.open(yourUrl)`.

b) Does your new destination require information that might have changed on the original record?  if so then you'll need to wait until the save completes.

The following will help with a=no and / or b=yes.

Before you trigger the save you drop a piece of information with the browser. And you have a piece of client script that will look for that piece of info so that when the page is reloaded you can use that information to load a new page.

The A algorithm will be:

1. leave a flag with instruction to redirect
2. trigger save
3. on load look for a redirect flag
4. if it is not there then break from this.
5. if it is there then do B.

The B algorithm will be:

1. copy the flag into a variable
2. remove the flag if it is there.
3. redirect based on the variable

You can use [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) of the browser as the place to store this flag. You could also use [`sessionstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which will expire when session is over.

for a pure NetSuite solution you could check with a suitelet that stores a session variable (`N/runtime`). A bit more work.

NB: Just remember to remove your flag or at least consider an expiration for that state (so do not follow it if it is "too old").

Comment: Thanks Gillyspy. I really appreciate your detailed response. At the moment, I have got the redirect working using the following:
 objRecord.save({
      enableSourcing: true,
      ignoreMandatoryFields: false,
    });

   

    window.location.assign(
      "https://app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=313&deploy=1&compid=TSTDRV&whence="
    );
  }
Though what you have posted is really helpful to understand how redirect will work

Comment: @Lefemmenikita trying to do something similar but didn't think you could fire objRecord.save({ enableSourcing: true, ignoreMandatoryFields: false, }); in a client side script?

Comment: @Chris, to be honest, I can't tell if that is working on not. It doesn't throw an error and the redirect works so I assume that part of the code is working correctly. I am very new to scripting this particular script is very much trial and error

Answer (score 1):

The netuiste native way to click the save button is to use the `getNLMultiButtonByName` global:

```js
window.getNLMultiButtonByName('multibutton_submitter').onMainButtonClick(this);
```

But the jQuery selector option should work too.